# How do I create a popup for a BrightCove video?

Tags: javascript, video, brightcove

I have two requirements:

1. I need to pop up a BrightCove video when an image is clicked on a desktop device.
2. For a mobile or tablet device the video should play in place.

I looked at the BrightCove API and saw nothing about doing a popup.
http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/index.html

Here is my code:

```
<!-- Start of Brightcove Player -->
<div style="display:none">
</div>
<!--
By use of this code snippet, I agree to the Brightcove Publisher T and C 
found at https://accounts.brightcove.com/en/terms-and-conditions/. 
-->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://admin.brightcove.com/js/BrightcoveExperiences.js"></script>
<object id="myExperience3331790840001" class="BrightcoveExperience">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
    <param name="width" value="252" />
    <param name="height" value="142" />
    <param name="playerID" value="3328690588001" />
    <param name="playerKey" value="AQ~~,AAABNxejUIE~,NjBzL2O70MzT703vlLFres21zOmPd7t1" />
    <param name="isVid" value="true" />
    <param name="isUI" value="true" />
    <param name="dynamicStreaming" value="true" />
    <param name="@videoPlayer" value="3331790840001" />
</object>
<!-- 
This script tag will cause the Brightcove Players defined above it to be created as soon
as the line is read by the browser. If you wish to have the player instantiated only after
the rest of the HTML is processed and the page load is complete, remove the line.
-->
<script type="text/javascript">brightcove.createExperiences();</script>
<!-- End of Brightcove Player -->
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you already got this figured out, but there is something for a "lightbox" implementation which might be useful for you:

http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/smart-player-api/samples/simple-lightbox-player.html

This might only be useful for playlists so you may have to be crafty, or contact Brightcove support and they'll probably be more helpful :).